# ListView setBackgroundResource not working android

Tags: java, android, background, android-viewbinder

I have problem wit changing backgroud color in my project. I'm just trying to change list background color with condition in ViewBinder. But color of backgroung didn't changing.

My ViewBinder

```
public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.listViewTopLinearLayout);
String voted = cursor.getString(VOTED_COLLUMN_INDEX);

    if (columnIndex == cursor.getColumnIndex(AssetsTableHelper.COLUMN_VOTED)) {
        boolean is_checked = voted.equals("true");
        if (is_checked) {
            ((View) ll.getParent()).setBackgroundResource(R.color.votedColor);
                ((View) view.getParent()).setBackgroundResource(R.color.votedColor);
        } else {
            ((View) view.getParent()).setBackgroundResource(R.color.notVotedColor);
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
};
```

onCreate

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
datasource = new AssetsDataSource(this);
Cursor cursor = datasource.getCursorForAllAssets();
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_item_row,cursor, UI_BINDING_FROM,UI_BINDING_TO, 0);
adapter.setViewBinder(new CustomViewBinder());
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

List_item_row.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSurname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvHomeNumber"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, problem is in argument of setBackgroundResource(R.color.votedColor). Argument should be a resource id for example some R.drawable.votedColor.
Take a look [setBackgroundResource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource%28int%29) and to make a drawable xml file take a look at [Drawable Resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html).